# Pandas preserve original columns when calculating mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset `df` looks like this. It is a `minute` based dataset

```
time, Open, High
2017-01-01 00:00:00, 1.2432, 1.1234
2017-01-01 00:01:00, 1.2432, 1.1234
2017-01-01 00:02:00, 1.2332, 1.1234
2017-01-01 00:03:00, 1.2132, 1.1234
...., ...., ....
2017-12-31 23:59:00, 1.2132, 1.1234
```

I did the following to calculate the `hourly` mean from the above `minute` dataset

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.index = df['time']
df_mean = df.resample('H').mean()
```

I then load `df_mean` and I get `hourly` value:

```
time,                 Open       High   
2017-01-01 00:00:00 1.051488    1.051500     
2017-01-01 01:00:00 1.051247    1.051275     
2017-01-01 02:00:00 1.051890    1.051957     
2017-01-01 03:00:00 1.051225    1.051290     
...., ...., ....
2017-12-31 23:00:00 1.051225    1.051290
```

but what I also want is the original `Open` value and `High` value

**I need help with two things:**

- Once the mean is calculated, I want it to be labeled `Open_Mean` and `High_Mean`
- Since the hourly mean gives `time` in `hour` basis(eg: `2017-01-01 01:00:00`), I want to load the original `Open` and `High` values at that time.

> **Here**:
>
> - `Open` and `High` values are the same for the particular `timestamp` form the original `dataset` but `Open_Mean` and `High_Mean` is the
>     calculated hourly `mean` for that `timestamp`

The new `df` should look like this:

> ```
> time,                 Open          High     Open_Mean   High_Mean    
> 2017-01-01 00:00:00   1.051488    1.051500   1.051500    1.051500 
> 2017-01-01 01:00:00   1.051247    1.051275   1.051500    1.051500
> 2017-01-01 02:00:00   1.051890    1.051957   1.051500    1.051500  
> 2017-01-01 03:00:00   1.051225    1.051290   1.051500    1.051500  
> ...., ...., ...., ...., ....
> 2017-12-31 23:00:00   1.051225    1.051290   1.051500    1.051500
> ```

Once we get the correct `dataset` in `df` I want to filter the new `df` to load only `time` specific data.

For eg: load data for `time range` form `10 PM - 4 PM` every day. Currently it load all hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `add_suffix` to rename

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df_mean = df.set_index('time').resample('H').mean()

df_mean = df_mean.add_suffix('_Mean')
```

and `merge` with `how='inner'` to extract the data on the hours:

```
df.merge(df_mean, left_on='time', right_index=True, how='inner')
```

Output (head of random data);

```
                    time      Open      High  Open_Mean  High_Mean
0    2017-01-01 00:00:00  1.219690  1.693049   1.519751   2.042550
60   2017-01-01 01:00:00  1.688490  1.404521   1.526833   2.115046
120  2017-01-01 02:00:00  1.015285  2.653544   1.533529   1.797564
180  2017-01-01 03:00:00  1.357672  2.299571   1.506012   2.043484
240  2017-01-01 04:00:00  1.293786  2.312414   1.489759   2.131644
300  2017-01-01 05:00:00  1.040048  2.791968   1.438353   1.816585
360  2017-01-01 06:00:00  1.225080  1.505802   1.473208   2.193237
420  2017-01-01 07:00:00  1.145402  3.217261   1.481710   1.914683
```

Comment: Amazing! thank you. One last question: how do I filter only specific hours? such as `10 PM - 4 PM` every day? I just want to see this data.

Comment: `df[df['time'].dt.hour.between(10, 15)]` gives you 10AM to before 4PM.

Comment: What I am looking for is a time overlap between two days, such as `2017-01-01 22:00:00` to `2017-01-02 04:00:00`

Comment: That's `10PM - 4AM`? `df[~df['time'].dt.hour.between(4, 22)]`?

Comment: thanks, it is working. what is `~` in front of `df`

Comment: It means `not`, negates the series that follows.

Comment: I also see that if we do not put `~` then we `swap` the value of `between(4, 22)`? so basically if we want `time-range` in a single day, we use `df[df['time'].dt.hour.between(10, 15)]` which give `time-range` from `10AM to before 4PM` and if we want `time-range` that combines 2 days, we use `df[~df['time'].dt.hour.between(4, 22)]`. Am I getting it correct?

Comment: [`Last Question`] Could you also please kindly let me know how can I `sum` the data in the `time-range` and put it in a different `data frame` for example `df_sum`? The tricky part is the `time` column because `time-range` lies in 2 different `date-range`. If we can have `time` column specify the `date-range` like (`2017-01-01 - 2017-01-02`) would be helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: I think it's more appropriate for a new question as it's not that simple to answer in a comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196544/discussion-between-floss-and-quang-hoang).